# how to match the start and end of an expression with grep in R

Tags: r

I am trying to match the start and end of expressions with grep command, but I am not able to do that. for example consider the following expressions.

```
filenames <- c("S2abc.6h", "S2abc.4h", "S2abc.0h","S4abc.6h","S2xyz.6h")
```

I want to fins all the files starting with S2 and ending with 6h. I can select the files starting with S2 using:

```
grep("S2", filenames, value = TRUE)
```

But I am not able to use the wild cards with grep.

```
> grep("S2*6h", filenames, value = TRUE)

 character(0)
```

Comment: There are no files which end with 06

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think your approach to use `grep` is fine, you only need to slightly tweak the regular expression you use to match the filenames you want.

```
> matches <- grep("^S2.*\\.6h$", filenames, ignore.case = T)
> matches
[1] 1 5
> filenames[matches]
[1] "S2abc.6h" "S2xyz.6h"
```

The regex I used is:

```
^S2.*\\.6h$
```

This will match any filename which begins with `S2` and ends with `.6h`

Comment: But I found  through my search that it can be done with perl = TRUE.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `^` to determine the start and `$` to determine the end of a string. The `.+` catches everything inbetween.

```
grep("^S2.+6h$", filenames, value = TRUE)
# [1] "S2abc.6h" "S2xyz.6h"
```